# Is it possible to have one Kafka consumer thread per topic?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have Springboot application that uses Spring-Kafka (2.1.7). We have enabled concurrency, so we can have one consumer thread per partition. So currently, if we have 3 topics, each with 2 partitions, there will be 2 consumer threads as shown below:

ConsumerThread1 - [topic1-0, topic2-0, topic3-0] 
ConsumerThread2 - [topic1-1, topic2-1, topic3-1]

However, instead of a one KafkaListener (or consumer thread) per partition, we would like to have **one consumer thread per topic**. For example:

ConsumerThread1 - [topic1-0, topic1-1] 
ConsumerThread2 - [topic2-0, topic2-1] 
ConsumerThread3 - [topic3-0, topic3-1]

If that is not possible, even the following setup is fine:

ConsumerThread1 - [topic1-0] 
ConsumerThread2 - [topic1-1] 
ConsumerThread3 - [topic2-0] 
ConsumerThread4 - [topic2-1] 
ConsumerThread5 - [topic3-0] 
ConsumerThread6 - [topic3-1]

The catch is that **we do not know the complete list of topics before hand** (we are using the wildcard topic pattern). A new topic can be added at any time, and a new consumer thread (or threads) should be created for this new topic dynamically during run-time.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: I can only think that you need to write your own Kafka partition assignment strategy class for this.

Answer (score 5):

You can create separate containers for each topic from [spring-kafka:2.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#container-factory) and set concurrency 1, so that each containers will consume from each topic

> Starting with version 2.2, you can use the same factory to create any ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer. This might be useful if you want to create several containers with similar properties or you wish to use some externally configured factory, such as the one provided by Spring Boot auto-configuration. Once the container is created, you can further modify its properties, many of which are set by using container.getContainerProperties(). The following example configures a ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>(
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory) {

ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container =
    factory.createContainer("topic1", "topic2");
container.setMessageListener(m -> { ... } );
return container;
}
```

**Note :** Containers created this way are not added to the endpoint registry. They should be created as @Bean definitions so that they are registered with the application context.

Comment: Or you can use a custom partitioner.

Comment: Another alternative is to add 3 @KakaListener annotations to the method and you’ll get 3 containers,

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to suggestions by [@Gary Russel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell), I was able to come up with the following solution which creates a `@KafkaListener` bean instance (or consumer thread) per Kafka topic. This way, if there is an issue with messages belonging to a particular topic, it will not affect the processing of other topics.

**Note** - The following code throws a `InstanceAlreadyExistsException` exception during startup. However, this does not seem to affect the functionality. Using the log outputs I'm able to verify that there is one bean instance (or thread) per topic, and they are able to process messages.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConsumerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Starting spring boot KafkaConsumerApp..");
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaConsumerApp.class, args);
    }

}


@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Value("${kafka.brokers:localhost:9092}")
    private String bootstrapServer;

    @Value("${kafka.consumerClientId}")
    private String consumerClientId;

    @Value("${kafka.consumerGroupId}")
    private String consumerGroupId;

    @Value("${kafka.topicMonitorClientId}")
    private String topicMonitorClientId;

    @Value("${kafka.topicMonitorGroupId}")
    private String topicMonitorGroupId;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaConfiguration( KafkaProperties kafkaProperties ) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory( consumerFactory( consumerClientId, consumerGroupId ) );
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode( ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL );
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> topicMonitorContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory( consumerFactory( topicMonitorClientId, topicMonitorGroupId ) );
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode( ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL );
        factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener( new KafkaRebalanceListener( context ) );
        return factory;
    }

    private ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory( String clientId, String groupId ) {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.putAll( kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties() );
        config.put( ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer );
        config.put( ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId );
        config.put( ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId );
        config.put( ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false ); // needs to be turned off for rebalancing during topic addition and deletion
                                                                    // check -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264681/is-it-possible-to-have-one-kafka-consumer-thread-per-topic/56274988?noredirect=1#comment99401765_56274988
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>( config, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer() );
    }
}


@Configuration
public class KafkaListenerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public KafkaMessageListener kafkaMessageListener() {
        return new KafkaMessageListener();
    }

}


@Slf4j
public class KafkaMessageListener {

    /*
     * This is the actual message listener that will process messages. It will be instantiated per topic.
     */
    @KafkaListener( topics = "${topic}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory" )
    public void receiveHyperscalerMessage( ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, Consumer<String, String> consumer ) {

        log.debug("Kafka message - ThreadName={}, Hashcode={}, Partition={}, Topic={}, Value={}", 
                Thread.currentThread().getName(), Thread.currentThread().hashCode(), record.partition(), record.topic(), record.value() );

        // do processing

        // this is just a sample acknowledgment. it can be optimized to acknowledge after processing a batch of messages. 
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }

}


@Service
public class KafkaTopicMonitor {

    /*
     * The main purpose of this listener is to detect the rebalance events on our topic pattern, so that 
     * we can create a listener bean instance (consumer thread) per topic. 
     *
     * Note that we use the wildcard topic pattern here.
     */
    @KafkaListener( topicPattern = ".*abc.def.ghi", containerFactory = "topicMonitorContainerFactory" )
    public void monitorTopics( ConsumerRecord<String, String> record ) {
        // do nothing
    }

}


@Slf4j
public class KafkaRebalanceListener implements ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener {

    private static final ConcurrentMap<String, KafkaMessageListener> listenerMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public KafkaRebalanceListener( ConfigurableApplicationContext context ) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onPartitionsRevokedBeforeCommit(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // do nothing
    }

    public void onPartitionsRevokedAfterCommit(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // do nothing
    }

    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {

        log.info("OnPartitionsAssigned - partitions={} - {}", partitions.size(), partitions);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast( new PropertiesPropertySource("topics", props) );

        for( TopicPartition tp: partitions ) {

            listenerMap.computeIfAbsent( tp.topic(), key -> {
                log.info("Creating messageListener bean instance for topic - {}", key );
                props.put( "topic", key );
                // create new KafkaMessageListener bean instance
                return context.getBean( "kafkaMessageListener", KafkaMessageListener.class );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom Partitioner to allocate the partitions however you want. It's a kafka consumer property.

**EDIT**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226984/how-to-listen-to-dynamic-destinations-using-spring-boot/56227817#56227817).

It is for a `@JmsListener` but the same technique can be applied to kafka too.

Comment: Will this create consumer threads dynamically, i.e. when a new topic is created? Also, do you have an example of custom partitioner for a consumer?

Comment: You still need to select concurrency. I am not available this week. It's pretty straightforward though. Look at the default partitioner for an example.

Comment: Another alternative is to add 3 @KakaListener annotations to the method and you’ll get 3 containers,

Comment: Problem is, the number of topics can increase during run-time, therefore we need to dynamically increase the number of containers (or threads). The setConcurrency works properly during start-up. However, if I increase this value during run-time, it doesn't seem to create new containers.

Comment: Also, I didn't come across a custom partitioner mechanism for consumers (other than for using the assign method).

Comment: You can stop and start the containers to change the concurrency and subscribed topics. See the Kafka documentation about the partitioner. There are many ways to do what you want. I will provide examples next week.

Comment: See the edit to my answer for a link to another answer which shows one technique to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks! That works nicely for the topics known during startup time. However, if a new topic is added later, I do not have a handle to create the new listener bean instance, because the wild-card topic pattern is no longer being used. So the RebalanceListener does not receive the rebalance event. Do you know any way to get around this issue?

Comment: You can create your own `Consumer`, with a different `group.id` such as `topicMonitor` that subscribes to the pattern. It won't actually consume anything, just detect the addition of new topics; when it detects a new topic, get another instance of the bean from the application context after setting the environment property.

Comment: What should be the behavior when a topic is deleted? Should I call the destroy() method in the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry?

Comment: You shouldn't ask new questions in comments; the admins here don't like long commentary on questions/answers. You should not delete a topic with an active consumer. When I tested it, the kafka-clients went into a tailspin and Spring never gets control back. If it did, calling `stop()` on the container would work, but since the `poll()` never exits in this case, it doesn't. Calling `destroy()` on the registry won't do anything.

Comment: Update: **correction** - the tailspin only occurs when `enable.auto.commit` is `true`. When it's `false`, the container does get control back, eventually a rebalance occurs with no partitions assigned. You can call `stop()` on the container and it will terminate. You can't remove it from the registry, though.